# How to replace an OpenGL Widget in a QT layout?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, pyopengl, pyqtgraph

I created a Window in Qt Designer and added a OpenGL Widget as the main Display widget.
In my main Code I now want to exchange this OpenGL Widget with a pyqtgraph.OpenGl.GlViewWidget, but the original behaviour is lost when I do it like this:

```
# Qt Designer generated Code
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1282, 721)
        self.close_Application = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.close_Application.setObjectName(u"close_Application")
        
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout_2")
        self.graphicsView = QOpenGLWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName(u"graphicsView")

        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.graphicsView)


# my Main.py script

from PySide2.QtWidgets import *  
import pyqtgraph.opengl as gl  
from PySide2.QtGui import * 

class RegistrationApp(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
     def __init__(self):

            super().__init__()
            self.setupUi(self)
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(r"./icon.PNG"))
            self.horizontalLayout_2.removeWidget(self.graphicsView)
            self.graphicsView = gl.GLViewWidget(self.centralwidget)
            self.graphicsView.setObjectName(u"graphicsView")
            self.graphicsView.setGeometry(QRect(9, 9, 933, 620))
            self.graphicsView.opts['distance'] = 200
            self.graphicsView.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Preferred)
            self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.graphicsView)
```

Everything works as expected when I change it in the Ui_MainWindow class, but this is against the idea of Qt designer since I have to change it every time I make a change in the ui file.
Is there a way of replacing the original Widget?

[image: pyqtgraph.GLViewWidget overlapping the control buttons after adding it in]

Comment: You say "the original behaviour is lost when I do it like this", what do you mean?

Comment: Sry should have clarified that. Since everything is within layouts the scaleabilty is conserved. When I maximize the window the viewWidget doesnt expand with it.
As you can see in the image, when I make the window smaller the ViewWidget overlays the buttons.

Comment: I don't understand. If you don't want the `QOpenGLWidget`, why are you adding it?

Comment: I want something like the QOpenGlWidget but not exactly this. If you have an answer on how to do it, I would love to hear it. I am pretty new to this QT stuff and these layouts are complicated. If I only add the graphicsView with my own code, it gets added left to the buttons, so I thought I place in a proxy and exchange it.

Comment: If you're using a box layout and you want to add a widget between existing ones, use `insertWidget(index, widget)` instead of `addWidget()`.

Comment: that worked! I had to figure things out like setting the layoutStretch correctly, but the insertWidget() function worked like a charm! Thank you!